# Convert Htaccess to Web for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm running Apache With .htaccess rules Defined  As i mentioned below i have Converted My Wordpress To Windows Server now i want To convert My Htaccess To Web.config is Can someone Do it.

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)kowalski\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www..com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^rogerbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^dotbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^gigabot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteBot
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*37f298cd809513afc7fbca54ca626089.*$
RewriteRule ^fffsd-cs-post.php - [F,L]
```

Comment: Have you [tried using Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=htaccess+to+web+config) at all?

Comment: yup GOOGLe Failed TO Fix :D

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Google seemed to work for me, enjoy.

```
<rule name="rule 1q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index\.php$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="."  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/http://www..com/"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4q">
    <match url=".*"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 5q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^fffsd-cs-post.php"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
</rule>
```